# Going through the vertices of graph as a method of this vertex

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a problem that I am not able to resolve at the moment.

Let's say I have a class `Member`, containing the info about the list of members who are connected with the given one:
`ArrayList<Member> links;`

Also, there is a method of this class called `canBeLinked(Member member)`,

which obviously returns boolean defining whether a particular member can be linked with given one both directly or indirectly.

By saying "directly" I mean common relation A -> B; if e.g. A -> B, and B -> C, then it should also return true.
Also keep in mind that if A -> B, then B -> A. 
So we got the model of an undirected graph.

My confusion is how to implement this function; I guess it must be recursive, but the point is it is not the function of two arguments (for example if it was static function we could easily write function `canBeLinked(Member a, Member b)`, there are a lot of implementations of such graphs around the internet).

My first approach was to write something like that:

```
public boolean canBeLinked(Member member) {
   if (this.links.contains(member)) {
       return true;
   }
   else {
       for (Member m : links)
           if (m.canBeLinked(member)) return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

I definitely gonna get a StackOverflowException;
 let's say we have such relations:

```
A -> B
B -> D
B -> E
D -> C
E -> C
```

when calling

```
a.canBeLinked(c)
```

we get: 
  1) firstly we check if "c" is already in the list of members for "a"; 
  2) it's not true so step into the for loop;
  3) as we have only one member in the list (it's "b"), we are calling b.canBeLinked(c);
  4) "c" is also not a member of the list for "b", so it also steps into the "for" statement
  5) now we are in trouble since "b"'s list contains not only "e" and "d", but also "a", which leads us to p.1; it's gonna last forever (well until the memory runs out)

Could you please explain how to resolve this issue? I'm pretty sure it is an easy one but I just got stuck with that and definitely missing some key point of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately the fix is rather simple; you need to keep track of which `Members` have already been visited in your search, e.g. using a `Set<Member>`, and not cycle back to visit any `Members` that have already been seen. Before querying linked `Members` you add the current `Member` to the set of visited.

Since your recursive function now needs to pass around the set of visited members it's good to split it off into a `private` or `protected` method that you call from your public method.

```
public boolean canBeLinked(Member member) 
{
  return canBeLinked(member, new HashSet<>());
}

private boolean canBeLinked(Member member, Set<Member> visited)
{
  if (this.links.contains(member)) {
      return true;
  }
  else {
    visited.add(this);
    for (Member m : links)
    {
      if (!visited.contains(m)) return m.canBeLinked(member, visited);
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```